# Should autowired fields be 'volatile' in Spring (tests)?

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-test

In his talk, [REST-Ful API Design (1:21:06)](https://youtu.be/oG2rotiGr90?t=1h21m6s), Ben Hale (Pivotal) very consciously write the `@Autowired` fields of his test class as `volatile`.

I have not been able to guess or find any reason why this would be necessary, but given that he knows what he's doing, what's the reason for it?

Comment: the same reason why some people declare all locals as `final` or put `{` on new line. We people just want to be different :)

Comment: Because he thinks its trendy, sort of how hipsters think they are trendy.

Comment: That's also what I thought, but I wanted to be open to the possibility that there were non-trivial edge cases or something. While `final` and newlines everywhere are harmless, I really don't understand why you would do extra (non-stylistic) work to make your code unnecessarily less efficient.